# local variables in an event Handling method and garbage collection

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, event-handling

I'm new to c# programming so bear with me, there is a concept I couldn't understand in the event handling pattern, here a simple implementation to an event handling

```
class test
{
 someobject.Click += OnClick;
 private void OnClick(object sender,EventArgs e)
 {
   SomeClass someclass = new SomeClass();
 }
```

}
    
the problem is why the variable `someclass` doesn't get garbage collected since it's a **local variable** in the method OnClick and gets out of scope when this method finishes

Comment: `someclass` will get garbage collected, at some point after your line `SomeClass someclass = new SomeClass();`. Why do you think it doesn't?

Comment: this is  just a pseudocode in the real one the onclick method creates an instance of the form class the problem is with each click a new instance created and the memory usage increases up to 1.5 gb after several clicks i marked each instance with an object id than forcing a garbage collection the result is object is still there is the garbage collection is not fast enough to prevent this huge increase in the memory usage ?

Comment: Then you need to ask your actual question, including your actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does get released, just not right away. Garbage collection occurs when

> The system has low physical memory. This is detected by either the low memory notification from the OS or low memory as indicated by the host.
>
> The memory that is used by allocated objects on the managed heap surpasses an acceptable threshold. This threshold is continuously adjusted as the process runs.
>
> The GC.Collect method is called. In almost all cases, you do not have to call this method, because the garbage collector runs continuously. This method is primarily used for unique situations and testing.

This means that you can't be certain when `SomeClass` is getting freed unless you call for the collection yourself.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals

Comment: thank you for your answer i'm aware of this approach i have an application that handles events let's say with each click a new form created after a several clicks the application that starts with 40 mb of memory usage ends up with up to 1.5 gb of memory usage which is not an acceptable behavior  i will accept this as answer    because i had a doubt about the local variables in the event handling methods is there any way to prevent this behavior ?