# Memory leak in Blazor Server-side project

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, blazor-server-side

I made a simple system to add and delete file from an EF Core database like this :

- Add a file :

  ```
  public async Task AddFile(IFileListEntry file)
  {
      File fileToAdd = await File.GetFileAsync(file);
      _context.Files.Add(fileToAdd);
      _context.SaveChanges();
  }
  ```
- Get the file from an `IFileListEntry` interface, containing the file into a `Stream` :

  ```
  public static async Task<File> GetFileAsync(IFileListEntry file)
  {
      using MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
      await file.Data.CopyToAsync(ms);
      File f = new File
      {
          Name = file.Name,
          Type = file.Type,
          Size = file.Size,
          LastModified = file.LastModified,
          Data = ms.ToArray(),
      };
      ms.Dispose();
      return f;
  }
  ```
- Remove a file :

  ```
  public void DeleteFile(File file)
  {
      file.Data = new byte[0]; //Test
      _context.Files.Remove(file);
      _context.SaveChanges();
  }
  ```

All the files added are stored into a `List`, and deleted from it, and the list itself is contained into `.razor` file (not shown here as I think it's irrelavant to my problem), and also in an EF Core database.

The database context `_context` is obtained through depedency injection and inherits from `DbContext` class.

So my problem is : after adding and deleting a file, I can observe a memory leak as the RAM is at the same level after the addition of the file into the database and the list.

So what I'm doing wrong ? I really can't understand where it could possibly come from, as the `MemoryStream` is disposed after its use, and when the file is deleted, I replace the filled `byte[]` by an empty one, or even a `null` reference. I made sure the `List` in my `.razor` file is a new empty list that we fill up again with the files added. I didn't test for the `_context` though.

Comment: "after adding and deleting a file, I can observe a memory leak as the RAM is at the same level after the addition of the file into the database and the list." That doesn't sound like a memory leak.  That's just how the .NET memory heaps work.

Comment: I'm not pointing out a memory leak coming from the Blazor or ASP.Net framework of course, I was just trying to figure out in which variable this unused and maybe useless allocated memory was being hold and how to dispose it, as it could take sometimes 100MB of RAM after one image upload, so something that could lead quickly to the RAM completely filled up with a few hundreds of uploads. @athanasios-kataras did answer to my question though and I'll try to dispose the context manually to get rid of this unused memory.

Answer (score 2):

I think that your DI container does not dispose the dbcontext.

[Check the dbcontext documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/working-with-dbcontext)

> The lifetime of the context begins when the instance is created and ends when the instance is either disposed or garbage-collected. Use using if you want all the resources that the context controls to be disposed at the end of the block. When you use using, the compiler automatically creates a try/finally block and calls dispose in the finally block.

```
public void UseProducts()
{
    using (var context = new ProductContext())
    {     
        // Perform data access using the context
    }
}
```

> If the context instance is created by a dependency injection container, it is usually the responsibility of the container to dispose the context.

So if your DI does not dispose the context, then it remains in memory and thus, it looks like you have a leak.

Another thing that may occur, is that the Garbage Collection does not occur predictably [check garbage collection here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59564071/local-variables-in-an-event-handling-method-and-garbage-collection/59564434#59564434). So it might take some time to see the freed memory.

One last thing: You don't need to `ms.Dispose();` [MemoryStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream?view=netframework-4.8)

> This type implements the IDisposable interface, but does not actually have any resources to dispose. This means that disposing it by directly calling Dispose() or by using a language construct such as using (in C#) or Using (in Visual Basic) is not necessary.

So the `MemoryStream` would not be the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it seems logicial now that it comes from the `DbContext` not being disposed. I can't really figure why the DI isn't disposing it though. So the solution would be to dispose it manually or use the `using` statement ? How could I apply one of those solutions knowing that I get this context through DI ? (Sorry for late answer, I just posted this before leaving work)

Comment: Depends on the DI. For example in net core https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext which says The AddDbContext extension method registers DbContext types with a scoped lifetime by default. So the disposal is handled by default. It depends on the DI implementation you are using.

Comment: My DI implementation is the one you obtain after creating a simple Blazor server-side project and the identity scaffolding, so the context injection is handled in the scaffolded `IdentityHostingStartupClass : IHostingStartup` class like this : `builder.ConfigureServices((context, services) => {
                    services.AddDbContext<MV2PollingInstituteContext>(options =>
                        options.UseSqlServer(
                            context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("...")));`

Comment: After more testing, I came up on very weird facts : after a certain number of upload, the GC seems doing his job and the RAM is stabilizing at a value of 400MB approximatively, although I still don't understand why. Same thing if you spam click on a navbar tab, the RAM keep increasing until one point where the GC is collecting and then the RAM keep stable. I really don't understand the "magic" going down there but at least it seems the memory leaks can be avoided by "itself". Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Cheers! Seems that it is some GC magic in place. The method you are using for DI disposes properly the context so you should be ok!

Comment: Without a doubt the MemoryStream could be a problem. If any of the data is > 85k then it will get put on the large object heap. A potential solution is to use the Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream.